# How to make square lag matrices in R the fastest way?

Tags: r, performance, matrix, vector

There is a vector containing n elements and I want to make a square matrix out of it which is nbyn and has a special property. The colnum of the matrix is the lag operator of the original vector.

```
V = 1, 2, 3

A = 1 0 0
    2 1 0
    3 2 1
```

I tried the following functions, these work but a bit slow on a vector of ength 1000. Mean running time is 0.01 secs.

```
n <- 1000
testvector <- runif(n)
testmatrix <- matrix(0, ncol = n, nrow = n)
testpos <- which(row(testmatrix) + 1 < col(testmatrix))

Lag.matrix1 <- function(Start_Length, Start_Matrix, Start_Position, Start_Vector) {
  testmatrix2 <- suppressWarnings(matrix(c(Start_Vector, 0), ncol = Start_Length, nrow = Start_Length))
  testmatrix2[Start_Position] <- 0
  return(testmatrix2)
}

testpos1 <- which(row(testmatrix) + 1 > col(testmatrix))
testpos2 <- sequence(n:1)

Lag.matrix2 <- function(Start_Matrix, Start_Position1, Start_Position2, Start_Vector) {
  Start_Vector <- Start_Vector[Start_Position2]
  Start_Matrix[Start_Position1] <- Start_Vector
  return(Start_Matrix)
}

Lag.matrix3 <- function(Start_Position, Start_Vector) {
  Return_Matrix <- matrix(unlist(shift(Start_Vector, 0L:Start_Position, type = "lag", fill = 0)), ncol = Start_Position + 1, nrow = Start_Position + 1)
  return(Return_Matrix)
}

Lag.matrix4 <- function(Start_Length, Start_Matrix, Start_Position, Start_Vector) {
  Start_Vector <- rep(c(Start_Vector, 0), Start_Length)[1:Start_Length^2]
  Start_Matrix <- suppressWarnings(matrix(Start_Vector, ncol = Start_Length, nrow = Start_Length))
  Start_Matrix[Start_Position] <- 0
  return(Start_Matrix)
}

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  Lag.matrix1(Start_Length = n, Start_Matrix = testmatrix, Start_Position = testpos, Start_Vector = testvector),
  Lag.matrix2(Start_Matrix = testmatrix, Start_Position1 = testpos1, Start_Position2 = testpos2, Start_Vector = testvector),
  Lag.matrix3(Start_Position = n - 1, Start_Vector = testvector),
  Lag.matrix4(Start_Length = n, Start_Matrix = testmatrix, Start_Position = testpos, Start_Vector = testvector),
  times = 300
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use something like this:

```r
f3 <- function(x) {
    if (nmd <- !is.null(nms <- names(x)))
        names(x) <- NULL # so that names(r) is NULL
    n <- length(x)
    r <- if (n > 1L) c(vector(typeof(x), n - 1L), x)[sequence.default(rep.int(n, n), n:1L)] else x
    dim(r) <- c(n, n)
    if (nmd)
        dimnames(r) <- list(nms, nms)
    r
}
```

And maybe it is time to bump my bug report about `sequence.default` not recycling its first argument, so that we can replace `rep.int(n, n)` with `n` ... https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=18304

Comment: Taken up in [benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77330734/6574038), lightning fast! +1

Comment: cool! that's a superb trick of `vector` + `sequence`, +1!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sequence` like below (I don't think this is the "fastest" all over the world, but it should be fast as your want)

```
testmatrix[lower.tri(testmatrix, diag = TRUE)] <- testvector[sequence(n:1)]
```

## example output

for `n <- 10`, we can obtain something like

```
> testmatrix
           [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
 [1,] 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [2,] 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [3,] 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [4,] 0.5473042 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [5,] 0.6095777 0.5473042 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [6,] 0.3081830 0.6095777 0.5473042 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000
 [7,] 0.1640612 0.3081830 0.6095777 0.5473042 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592
 [8,] 0.8473997 0.1640612 0.3081830 0.6095777 0.5473042 0.6809973 0.2012220
 [9,] 0.1770707 0.8473997 0.1640612 0.3081830 0.6095777 0.5473042 0.6809973
[10,] 0.5862107 0.1770707 0.8473997 0.1640612 0.3081830 0.6095777 0.5473042
           [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
 [1,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [2,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [4,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [5,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [6,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [7,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [8,] 0.4974592 0.0000000 0.0000000
 [9,] 0.2012220 0.4974592 0.0000000
[10,] 0.6809973 0.2012220 0.4974592
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it out, it gave 0.02 secs, so it's a bit slow, can you suggest a different approach?

Comment: @matehorvath do you have a benchmark? Is this slower than your approaches? I don't have other idea but we can wait for some other answers.

Comment: I measured it by the microbenchmark function:
Lag.matrix5 <- function(Starter_Length, Start_Matrix, Start_Vector) {
  Start_Matrix[lower.tri(Start_Matrix, diag = TRUE)] <- Start_Vector[sequence(Starter_Length:1)]
  return(Start_Matrix)
}

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  Lag.matrix5(Starter_Length = n, Start_Matrix = testmatrix, Start_Vector = testvector),
  times = 300
)

Answer (score 1):

We could loop over an incrementing `rle` structure with `vapply`.

```
f2 <- \(v) {
  vapply(seq_len(length(v)) - 1, \(i) {
    rl <- list(lengths=c(i, c(rep.int(1L, length(v) - i), rep.int(0, i))), 
               values=c(0, v))
    with(rl, rep.int(values, lengths))
  }, numeric(length(v)))
}

> f2(c(12, 13, 14))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   12    0    0
[2,]   13   12    0
[3,]   14   13   12
```

### Benchmark

```
f1 <- \(v) {
  n <- length(v)
  testmatrix <- matrix(0, n, n)
  testmatrix[lower.tri(testmatrix, diag = TRUE)] <- v[sequence(n:1)]
  testmatrix
}
f2 <- \(v) {
  vapply(seq_len(length(v)) - 1, \(i) {
    rl <- list(lengths=c(i, c(rep.int(1L, length(v) - i), rep.int(0, i))), 
               values=c(0, v))
    with(rl, rep.int(values, lengths))
  }, numeric(length(v)))
}
v <- runif(1e4)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(lower.tri=f1(v), rep.int=f2(v), check='identical', times=10L)



$ Rscript --vanilla foo.R
Unit: milliseconds
             expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
        lower.tri 3497.2215 3566.804 3820.758 3843.171 4042.649 4183.080    10 a  
          rep.int 2363.2630 2424.569 2488.397 2497.333 2537.866 2639.833    10  b  
 sequence.default  948.8763  956.035 1054.595 1067.129 1139.331 1154.017    10   c
```

Comment: impressive performance by `vapply` + `rle`, +1!

Answer (score 0):

Sparse matrices may work well here:

```
library(Matrix)

f4 <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  n1 <- n:1L
  new("dtCMatrix", i = sequence(n1, 0:(n - 1L)), p = c(0L, cumsum(n1)),
      Dim = rep(n, 2), Dimnames = rep(list(names(x)), 2),
      x = x[sequence(n1, 1L)], uplo = "L", diag = "N")
}
```

Benchmarking:

```
n <- 1000
x <- runif(n)

f3 <- function(x) {
  if (nmd <- !is.null(nms <- names(x)))
    names(x) <- NULL # so that names(r) is NULL
  n <- length(x)
  r <- if (n > 1L) c(vector(typeof(x), n - 1L), x)[sequence.default(rep.int(n, n), n:1L)] else x
  dim(r) <- c(n, n)
  if (nmd)
    dimnames(r) <- list(nms, nms)
  r
}

bench::mark(
  sequence.default = f3(x),
  sparse = f4(x),
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression            min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>       <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 sequence.default   2.47ms   2.54ms      365.   11.48MB     236.
#> 2 sparse             2.37ms   2.54ms      368.    7.87MB     113.
```

---

### Update

In response to the comment about repeated matrix creation:

If this process is being repeated many times with different starting vectors of the same size, initializing the matrix and the indexing will definitely speed it up. For example, say you had a `n`-by-`k` matrix, `x`, and you wanted to create a lower triangular matrix, `m`, for each column of `x` and then perform matrix multiplication on each lower triangular matrix with a vector, `v`, of length `n` (`m %*% v`). Below are three functions that each perform these calculations using slightly different strategies.

The first uses base matrices and pre-calculates the "to" (`j`) and "from" (`i`) indices to map each column of `x` to a lower triangular matrix.

```
library(Matrix)

f3m <- function(x, v) {
  # base matrix
  # initialize the lower triangular matrix and indexing
  n <- nrow(x)
  m <- matrix(vector(typeof(x), 1L), n, n)
  i <- sequence(n:1L, 1L)
  j <- sequence(n:1L, seq(1L, n*n, n + 1L))
  
  for (k in 1:n) {
    m[j] <- x[i, k] # update the lower triangular matrix
    x[,k] <- m %*% v # perform the matrix multiplication
  }
  
  x
}
```

The next function uses a sparse matrix from the `Matrix` package. The sparse matrix stores only the non-zero elements of the lower triangular matrix, so there is no need for the "to" indices.

```
f4m <- function(x, v) {
  # dtCMatrix (triangular sparse column matrix)
  # initialize the lower triangular matrix and indexing
  n <- nrow(x)
  i <- sequence(n:1L, 1L)
  m <- new("dtCMatrix", i = sequence(n:1L, 0:(n - 1L)), p = c(0L, cumsum(n:1L)),
           Dim = rep(n, 2), Dimnames = rep(list(names(x)), 2),
           x = vector(typeof(x), n*(n + 1L)/2L), uplo = "L", diag = "N")
  
  for (k in n:1L) {
    m@x <- x[i, k] # update the lower triangular matrix
    x[,k] <- (m %*% v)@x # perform the matrix multiplication
  }
  
  x
}
```

The last function uses a triangular matrix from the `Matrix` package. The "to" and "from" indexing is the same as with `f3m`.

```
f5m <- function(x, v) {
  # dtrMatrix (dense triangular matrix)
  # initialize the lower triangular matrix and indexing
  n <- nrow(x)
  m <- new("dtrMatrix", Dim = rep(n, 2), x = vector(typeof(x), n*n), uplo = "L")
  i <- sequence(n:1L, 1L)
  j <- sequence(n:1L, seq(1L, n*n, n + 1L))
  
  for (k in 1:n) {
    m@x[j] <- x[i, k] # update the lower triangular matrix
    x[,k] <- (m %*% v)@x # perform the matrix multiplication
  }
  
  x
}
```

Benchmarking:

```
n <- 1e3L
k <- 1e3L
x <- matrix(runif(n*k), n, k)
v <- rnorm(n)

bench::mark(
  f3m(x, v),
  f4m(x, v),
  f5m(x, v)
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 f3m(x, v)     4.44s    4.44s     0.225    3.76GB     14.6
#> 2 f4m(x, v)     3.76s    3.76s     0.266    3.76GB     23.4
#> 3 f5m(x, v)     6.61s    6.61s     0.151   11.22GB     32.7
```

Overall, using a sparse matrix is somewhat faster than using a base matrix. The triangular matrix is the slowest. Run two more benchmarks to further explore the performance of the three functions. First, time the creation of the lower triangular matrix.

```
m3 <- matrix(vector(typeof(x), 1L), n, n)
m4 <- new("dtCMatrix", i = sequence(n:1L, 0:(n - 1L)), p = c(0L, cumsum(n:1L)),
          Dim = rep(n, 2), Dimnames = rep(list(names(x)), 2),
          x = vector(typeof(x), n*(n + 1L)/2L), uplo = "L", diag = "N")
m5 <- new("dtrMatrix", Dim = rep(n, 2), x = vector(typeof(x), n*n), uplo = "L")
i <- sequence(n:1L, 1L)
j <- sequence(n:1L, seq(1L, n*n, n + 1L))

bench::mark(
  m3[j] <- x[i, k],
  m4@x <- x[i, k],
  m5@x[j] <- x[i, k],
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 m3[j] <- x[i, k]      2.6ms   2.79ms      352.   11.45MB     13.1
#> 2 m4@x <- x[i, k]      1.16ms   1.24ms      791.    3.82MB     47.6
#> 3 m5@x[j] <- x[i, k]   4.08ms   4.33ms      226.   11.45MB     40.3
```

Next, time the matrix multiplication.

```
bench::mark(
  x[,k] <- m3 %*% v,
  x[,k] <- (m4 %*% v)@x,
  x[,k] <- (m5 %*% v)@x,
  check = FALSE
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   expression                  min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>             <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 x[, k] <- m3 %*% v      788.3µs  815.6µs     1196.    7.64MB        0
#> 2 x[, k] <- (m4 %*% v)@x   1.73ms   1.87ms      521.   19.67KB        0
#> 3 x[, k] <- (m5 %*% v)@x  197.4µs  205.1µs     4723.   19.67KB        0
```

Surprisingly, the timings are dominated by the creation of the lower triangular matrices rather than the matrix multiplication.

---

A final note: it *may* be possible to further optimize the above functions by avoiding the creation of the lower triangle altogether and performing the multiplication directly on `x`. That may be the subject of a follow-on question if your actual problem resembles the one used here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This seems pretty interesting and useful. I tested it, on a vector of length 1000 it runs in 0,007 seconds. What do you think, can it be further optimised? Some calculations can be done before the function runs, because the length of the vector will be given, only its digits change.

Comment: As I understand your question, the answer is yes. See the update.